# Opencart modules and vqmod not working on custom templates

Tags: templates, module, opencart, vqmod

I have recently started a store powered by opencart. I have purchased a custom template for my store.

All has gone well for that- I thought. Then I purchased some modules and they are not working on the custom theme.

I have switched back to the default theme and everything works perfectly.
So I thought it was only because of the modules.. so I went ahead and purchased another module and it also does not work on my custom theme too.
Also, vqmods also don't work on my custom theme.

Here's my site:
http://www.bishounenboutique.com/

Scroll down to see the "blast of the past" modules, they all don't behave like they are supposed to. There are 3 of them: The list on the side, the carousel and the wall of images on the right.

I have also installed a vqmod for this page that shows all the images, it worked for the default but not for my custom:
http://www.bishounenboutique.com/series

I would like to know why this is? Is it because the custom template has its own settings and the modules need to be configured to fit the custom template? If I were to use these modules on a different theme, would they have to be customized to fit that specific theme too? I have been trying to google the problem but to no avail. If you need any files to examine the problem, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: The programmers who did the custom template didn't expected that case or they have deleted the support that the original theme has. Usually, it's about lazy programmers or those who are in a hurry. Ultimately, it's Opencart team fault because they don't have an API for extending the functionally of their software, like Wordpress has.

Comment: Normally all third party extension are compatible default OpenCart theme with vqmod. So, Some time create issue in third party extension with Custom theme. So, there, You will need to contact it third party extension support. if, here, you are use any third party module.

Answer (score 1):

The Krotek correctly explains why OpenCart does not always work with certain files. He mentions custom tuning which is never explained and an important thing to know how to do.

Custom Tuning:
Vqmod which uses a xml parser searches through files you have on your server. It can then execute something at the specified location in pre-existing code.

In your public_html folder you will find Vqmod and core files. Before you upload the code make sure it will work. You will find all you need to do with extensions is match them together (which requires some knowledge of programming).

Answer (score 0):

VQMod searches for EXACT strings in template and if none found, then it won't work. For example, standard template file contains this string:

```
<table name="sometable">
```

And yours have this:

```
<table id="customid" name="sometable">
```

This is quite enough for VQMod to fail.

You have to either tune VQMod to your template or ask a developer to do so. If you use custom template, always remember, that ALL template dependent extensions will NOT work for you and require custom tuning.

Answer (score 0):

I had thesame issue also, but got it fix after a long time research and hope this might help someone.

Modify the **vqmod/pathReplaces.php** file and add the following line to the end of the file replacing ***my-theme-name*** with the name of your **custom theme** folder.

```
$replaces[] = array('~\btheme/default\b~', 'theme/your-custom-theme');
```

This process makes VQMod use your custom theme